# Unable to fetch data from firebase firestore database with react native using state

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a react native app where I need to place all the data of users in a firebase firestore database into a flatlist. I am unsure of how to do this with all updated react native code, as all other stack overflow questions do not answer this question and I can not find any help elsewhere. 
My code for fetching the react native data is:

```
state = {
    data: []
  };

  unsubscribe = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid;
    const list = [];

    this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(data)
      .onSnapshot(doc => {
        list.push(data);
      });

      this.setState({
            data: list
      )};
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }
```

The database structure is that the user has a name and an email. I try to call this by typing: "{this.state.name.email}", which does not work in the Flatlist. I already initialized my app in another file, where Fire.shared = new Fire(); is exported. If any help would be given on how to export such data into the state properly, I would be largely grateful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `setState` needs to be in the callback, so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid;
  const list = [];

  this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
    .collection("users")
    .doc(data)
    .onSnapshot(doc => {
      list.push(data);
      this.setState({
        data: list
      )};
    });
}
```

Comment: When I use this code, I receive a new error that says, "TypeError: _Fire.default.shared.firestore.collection is not a function. (In '_Fire.default.shared.firestore.collection("users")','_Fire.default.shared.firestore.collection' is undefined)". I do not understand why this is giving the error as the solution seems fine.

Comment: I copied that part from your code, as I have no way to know what `Fire.shared` is. You might want to try accessing Firestore with `firebase.firestore().collection...`.

Comment: I see. This fixed my issue. Thank you for your help!